# Why are audio books more expensive than a movie ticket?

Tags: book, audiobook

Think of all the millions of dollars actors are paid, and all the thousands of people who scroll by in the credits. Surely the cost of a printed book can't be translated to an audio book. The concept of an audio book is much more closely related to a movie ticket than the printed version, yet the price of an audio book is much closer to the printed version.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is both a rant/discussion question and about setting the price of an item in another industry, both of which are off-topic for us. Please see take our tour and see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kind of topics we cover here.

Comment: audiobook off topic?

Comment: Audiobooks are on-topic. You could potentially have an on-topic question about audiobook prices — if you were self-publishing, perhaps. This is not such a question.

Comment: Usually many more people go to a movie than read a book, and many more people read a book than listen to it. It is a dedicated market, though, and people who *need* audiobooks buy them, even though the prices are higher than regular books. Can't read a book while driving! (Well, except in a Boston rush hour, perhaps.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an economics question

Comment: Personally speaking, I don't have any problem with questions trying to understand how the industry works -- including why a particular type of product is priced the way it is. I'd consider this on-topic, myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't.

BUYING an audio book is similar in price to BUYING a movie, be it DVD or digital copy. Going to the movies is just RENTING the movie. You can rent audiobooks such that the price for each audiobook would be less than a movie ticket.

Plus audio books are longer than movies, more equivalent to a TV season. Pricing for renting/owing a season of TV is similar to pricing for the longer audiobooks.

Answer (score 0):

Prices are set based on supply and demand. Cost of production has nothing to do with it, except to determine whether a product is worth producing.

Comment: I would have thought so as well, but the demand for movie tickets are much greater than audiobooks. So movie tickets should be even more expensive than audio books. The market for audiobooks are nowhere near the market for movies though so the cost of licensing rights can't be comparable. 

So if I were to buy the audio rights to a book and produce it I should be able to sell it at far cheaper rates than a printed book, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. Movie tickets and audiobooks are different commodities with their own supply and demand curves. The supply of movie tickets increases to meet the demand, driving down the price to the point where it is not attractive to bring more supply to market. The same thing happens with audiobooks, and pizzas, and potatoes and minvans. Coincidences between the prices of these different commodities are just that: coincidences.

Answer (score -1):

"I would have thought so as well, but the demand for movie tickets are much greater than audiobooks. So movie tickets should be even more expensive than audio books."

This is incorrect.  Higher demand generally leads to a *lower* price, not a higher one.

Secondly, a movie ticket is a one-off - you can't re-use it.  Whereas, once you own an audio book you're unlikely to re-buy that book.

Also, you have to hire a voice artist or actor to read your book.  It has to be published, DRM, etc., etc.

There's every reason for an audio book to be priced the same as the print version, and no reason at all for it to be cheaper than a movie ticket.